# Issue running function on apps script using onEdit for a custom PDF exporting function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, export-to-pdf

I appreciate the time you are taking to read/answer my case, basically, I have a function to export a certain range as a PDF report, this report is the result of a daily inspection I'm assigned at work, the function below is a function I adapted from some code I found, it exports the range "F1:O" of the sheet named "Report Generator (Automatic)", saves it to a folder on Drive and then mails the file and a message to the emails I specify (I will make it to get the emails from a certain range later):

```
function ExportAsPDF(range,shTabName) {
 var blob,exportUrl,name,options,response,sheetTabId,ss,ssID,url_base,range;

    range = range? range: "F1:O";//Set the default to whatever you want

    shTabName = "Report Generator (Automatic)";//Replace the name with the sheet tab name for your situation
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//This assumes that the Apps Script project is bound to a G-Sheet
    ssID = ss.getId();
    sh = ss.getSheetByName(shTabName);
    sheetTabId = sh.getSheetId();
    url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
    name = sh.getRange("E1").getValue();
    name = name + "- Supporting Report Evidence"

    //Logger.log('url_base: ' + url_base)

    exportUrl = url_base + 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +

      '&gid=' + sheetTabId + '&id=' + ssID +
      '&range=' + range + 
      //'&range=NamedRange +
      '&size=A4' +     // paper size//A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
      '&portrait=false' +   // orientation, false for landscape
      '&fitw=true' +       // fit to width, false for actual size
      '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=True&pagenumbers=CENTER' + //hide optional headers and footers
      '&gridlines=false' + // hide gridlines
      '&fzr=false' +       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      '&top_margin=0.15' +
      '&bottom_margin=0.15' +
      '&left_margin=0.15' +
      '&right_margin=0.15' +
      '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' +  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
      '&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE'+       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM'
      '&fzr=False'; // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

    //Logger.log('exportUrl: ' + exportUrl)

    options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      }
     }

    options.muteHttpExceptions = true;//Make sure this is always set

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options);

    //Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())

    if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
      console.log("Error exporting Sheet to PDF!  Response Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
      return;

    }
  
    blob = response.getBlob();
    blob.setName(name + '.pdf')
    var specified_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");    //specify folder ID
    var savedPDFfile= specified_folder.createFile(blob);     //saves the PDF to Drive
    var recipient='recipient@mail.com';
    var subject=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("'Report Generator (Automatic)'!E1").getValue().toString();
    var body="Hello,\n\nPlease find attached the test document.\n\nThank you,\n My name";
    var myemail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,{
    name: myemail,
    cc: 'CCmail@mail.com',
    attachments: [savedPDFfile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]})
     };
```

I created a trigger with this "Createtriggers" function to enable "ExportAsPDF" to run on edit as well, doesn't seem to do anything if I delete/insert it, I saw a thread about installable triggers but it was not very specific and last time I tried to deploy my file as an API executable it would just not allow me to run it anymore and there's a "quota" of the number of apps I can deploy (I think it was 12), anyway, this is the trigger I put on the same script:

```
function createTriggers() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('ExportAsPDF')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

The following functions were tested individually on the script (it's just one single script for a single file on Sheets), this is why they are all named "Onedit(e)", the output of all of them was an error of undefined range or "can't read undefined" error, so I simply deactivated each function  with "//" because they don't really work for me:

```
//function onEdit(e){
//var dropDownCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("'Report Generator (Automatic)'!B1").getValue().toString()

//if (dropDownCell == 'ExportAsPDF'){ 
  //return ExportAsPDF("F1:O","Report Generator (Automatic)")}

//if (dropDownCell == 'ExportAsPDF'){ 
 // dropDownCell.range().clear()}
//};    //*******function does not work

//function onEdit(e){
  //const rg = e.range;
  //if(rg.getA1Notation() === "B1" && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1"){
    //ExportAsPDF("F1:O","Report Generator (Automatic)");
    //rg.uncheck();
  //}
//}    //*******function does not work (changed the "Sheet1" parameter but doesn't do anything)

//function onEdit(e) {
  //if(e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Report Generator (Automatic)') {
    //if(e.range.getA1Notation()=='B1' && e.value=="TRUE") {
      //return ExportAsPDF("F1:O","Report Generator (Automatic)")}
  //};
//}    //*******function does not work
```

However, what I am required to do is taking pictures of some issues and then inform the corresponding department of them, which is done through the email and report I have generated, and it would be extremely practical and convenient for me to do it through my phone, this is why I have tried to adapt my "ExportAsPDF" function in such a way that it can be triggered on the Google Sheets mobile app by using a checkbox when it's True it should run the "ExportAsPDF" function and then reset as "False", this "OnEdit" function "combines" two separate functions, one is to trigger  "ExportAsPDF" with the checkbox located in cell B1, and the second one is a multi-select dropdown function for a column named "Root cause" on other sheets from the spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Report Generator (Automatic)');
var activeCell = sh.getActiveCell();
var range = range ? range : "F1:O";
var shTabName = "Report Generator (Automatic)";
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() == 1 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=='Report Generator (Automatic)') {
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue('FALSE');
}
if(e.value='TRUE') {
activeCell.setValue('FALSE'); //the function works until here
eval(ExportAsPDF)(range,shTabName); //then it "jumps" this step
}
}
//START OF MULTISELECTION FOR ROOT CAUSES FUNCTION
var oldValue; 
var newValue; //this function runs smoothly all over the other sheets (on cells with dropdown selection)
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 14 && activeCell.getRow() >= 8) {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue) <0) {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+','+'\n'+newValue); //Multiple selection list for root cause gets new value
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue);
}
}
}
}
}
```

My question is basically how can I get my "ExportAsPDF" to be triggered from a checkbox located in cell B1 from my "Onedit" function so I am able to export my reports using my phone (I have an android)? I have not deployed this as an API executable (not sure how to do so neither if I did it properly the last time, I assume I didn't), I have already set my "Onedit" and "ExportAsPDF" functions triggers as "onedit" on the trigger editor as well.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] please pay attention to the term minmal.

Comment: Greetings Cooper! I just figured out the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Simple triggers can not run methods that require authorisation, so this must run as an installable trigger.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers):

> [Simple Triggers] cannot access [services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services) that require [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization). For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail) requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the [Language service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language), which is anonymous.

As you are using `MailApp`, the simple trigger fails as authorisation is required to call its methods.

#### Fix:

- Change the name of your `onEdit()` trigger, something like `mailTrigger()` is fine.
- Save the script change
- Go to the Project Triggers page

  - In the legacy editor, follow the `Edit > Current project's trigger` menu item
  - In the new editor, click the Triggers menu item donated by the alarm clock
- In the bottom-right of the triggers page, click `+ Add Trigger`
- Set up the trigger with the following settings:

  - Choose which function to run: `mailTrigger` (change for your function name)
  - Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
  - Select event source: `From spreadsheet`
  - Select event type: `On edit`

And click `Save`. You may need to authorise the trigger.

#### Proof of concept:

As an example, I created a small function which sends an email and then sets the value of `A1` to a random number as proof that the function ran:

```
function sendMail(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail("myemail@domain.com", "test", "test")
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").setValue(Math.random())
}
```

After creating the Installable trigger for the project:

[image]

The script runs without issue from the Sheets mobile app:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Rafa! It was helpful and I figured a way to make my code work, it was just a matter of changing a few things from all my functions (I found it very useful to separate each function into an individual file [using the button "Add a file"). After this, I had to delete all my previous triggers from the triggers list.

Comment: If it fix it, you can accept his answer by clicking on the check mark (top left of his answer)